# Why is my component looking so different in dev console preview mode than in an actual tab?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-apps

I'm quite new to SF developing so you'll see me posting quite often.

I have developed this component that looks like this on preview mode in Dev Console (you know, when you click on the preview button in the .app application).

[image]

[image]

BUT

it's looking quite different (and more ugly) when I'm adding the component to a new Tab I've created

[image]

What is going on here and why is this looking so different ??

Many thanks :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The styles are actually messed up in the preview, too, but it's harder to tell because of the nearly-white background of a Lightning App. In the Lightning Experience, the branding is applied, which includes a blue background. This is where the difference in appearance comes from.

Try adding a colored background to the app and you'll see what I mean. You'll want to fix your code so that it conforms to the Lightning Design System, which may take significant rewrites from what I can tell from the images, or consider using standard elements (e.g. lightning:card) instead, as those will apply the styles correctly for you.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer !! This is not very nice from the Framework :(

Comment: So how do you actually KNOW if the component you're previewing is the same that you will see when you add it to a tab ? Like, is there a way to preview what I will actually will end up adding to the tab or I just have to know how to use it and pray ??

Comment: @NachoZveDeLaTorre Either add a background to the Lightning App, or add a container around your Lightning Component. The default behavior for a component is to have a transparent background, meaning whatever you don't explicitly set to a color will be see-through. This behavior is "nice" in that it helps the branding to show through, but you need to remember to consider this when using a "preview" app. I would recommend you look at [Themes](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/utilities/themes/) for examples of how to set a background for your component.

Comment: Thanks for the help my brother :D Very appreciated (sorry for my spelling) hahah